# Insert query results into table in ms access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to transform data from one schema into another in an MS Access database.  This involves writing queries to select data from the old schema and then inserting the results of the queries into tables in the new schema.  The below is an example of what I am trying to do.  The SELECT component of the below works fine, but the INSERT component does not work.  Can someone show me how to fix the below so that it effectively inserts the results of the SELECT statement into the destination table?

```
INSERT INTO CompaniesTable 
    (CompanyName) 
    VALUES
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            IIF(a.FIRM_NAME IS NULL, b.SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME, a.FIRM_NAME) AS CompanyName   
        FROM 
            (SELECT ContactID, FIRM_NAME, SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME FROM qrySummaryData) AS a
            LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT ContactID, FIRM_NAME, SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME FROM qrySummaryData) AS b
            ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID
    );
```

The definition of the target table (CompaniesTable) is:

```
CompanyID      Autonumber  
CompanyName    Text  
Description    Text  
WebSite        Text  
Email          Text  
TypeNumber     Number
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have a typo but joining a table to itself you don't need the join, this should work fine.  With an insert on a select statement you don't use the values keyword.

```
INSERT INTO CompaniesTable (CompanyName,Description,Website,Email,TypeNumber) 
    SELECT DISTINCT IIF(FIRM_NAME IS NULL, SUBACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME, FIRM_NAME), 
                    '','','',0 
    FROM qrySummaryData
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that, and it gave me similar results to something else I had tried earlier.  It outputs the data into query datasheet view perfectly, but then CompaniesTable still remains empty.  I need the results to insert into CompaniesTable.

Comment: @CodeMed - This statement is correct, does CompaniesTable have more columns -- maybe one which is non-null?

Comment: Yes, CompaniesTable has six fields, one of which is an autonumber key.  The entire table is empty prior to this query running.  I am using this query to test before writing/running something more complicated afterwards.

Comment: @CodeMed - please post the definition of the target table.

Comment: I just posted the definition of the target table at the end of my original posting above.  Any more ideas?

Comment: @CodeMed - ok try the change I posted above.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to think this through.  I tried your revised suggestion verbatim and it still does not insert anything into CompaniesTable.  I even tried using the AS keyword to label each field in the query datasheet when your verbatim version did not work, but that did not work either. Any more ideas?

Comment: @CodeMed - no idea can you post the exact code you are using that might help

Comment: The query in this answer works with your file for me once I change "Discription" to "Description"

Comment: @Jesse For the benefit of people who find this from search engines later, the trick to making it work was to close the database file and reopen it before running the query again.  Before I closed and reopened the database, it didn't matter how many times I ran the query, it never inserted data.

Comment: @Hogan +1 and credit for the answer.  Thank you for your patience, and for your help.